# LINQ Query comparing Id with an Id in a list inside SingleOrDefault query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to fetch an option using the SingleOrDefault Linq to SQL method.

```
 var po = repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>().SingleOrDefault(o => o.Option.Id == sp.Options // sp.Options is a collection);
```

The problem is that inside the SingleOrDefault method I am comparing p.Option.Id == a collection. What I want is to select the option from sp.Options that matches the o.Option.Id. How can I do that?

UPDATE: 
One thing I should have mentioned that the sp.Options is a different class than the Option class. sp.Options is SPOptions class so I cannot pass it inside the contains method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>().SingleOrDefault(o => sp.Options.Contains(o.Option.Id));
```

If Options is not a collection of the class of Option.Id, you can use the [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) method with your comparison logic in it as follow :

```
repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>().SingleOrDefault(o => sp.Options.Any(opts => opts.Something == o.Option.Id));
```

Comment: One thing I should have mentioned that the sp.Options is a different class than the Option class. sp.Options is SPOptions class so I cannot pass it inside the contains method.

Answer (score 4):

Search using [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338641(v=vs.100).aspx) `(sp.Options.Contains(o.Option.Id))` like:

```
var po = repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>()
                    .SingleOrDefault(o => sp.Options.Contains(o.Option.Id));
```

If members of `sp.Options` are different from `Id` then you can do:

```
var po = repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>()
                    .SingleOrDefault(o => sp.Options.Any(r=> r.Id == o.Option.Id));
```

or

```
var po = repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>()
                    .SingleOrDefault(o => sp.Options.Select(r=> r.Id).Contains(o.Option.Id));
```

*Assuming `Id` is the field in `sp.Options` elements that you want to compare with.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it seems you're expecting to have a single match between those two option sets, correct ?
If so, I'd suggest you to write it as:

var po = repository.Context.AsQueryable().Where(o => sp.Options.Any(item=>item.id == o.Option.Id)).SingleOrDefault();